# Concatenate column values of multiple rows based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a specific output that one of our vendors are requesting. The format that we currently store our data and the format that they would like to manipulate the data are slightly different.

As an example, this is how I currently have the data stored in a temporary table:

| s_case_id | case_id | customString | last_updated_date | udef_field_name | value_set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Parking Meter #: xxxxxxx | 2023-01-04 17:35:08.000 | Parking Meter # | xxxxxxx |
| 10 | 10 | Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Permit Valid From: 08 Dec 2008 | 2023-01-04 17:35:07.000 | Permit Valid From | 08 Dec 2008 |
| 10 | 10 | Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Permit Valid To: 12 Dec 2008 | 2023-01-04 17:35:07.000 | Permit Valid To | 12 Dec 2008 |
| 10 | 10 | Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Receipt # (if applicable):: xxxxx | 2023-01-04 17:35:07.000 | Receipt # (if applicable): | xxxxx |

And this is my desired output:

| s_case_id | case_id | customString |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Parking Meter #: xxxxxxx, Permit Valid From: 08 Dec 2008, Permit Valid To: 12 Dec 2008, Receipt # (if applicable):: xxxxx |

Just in case anyone is wondering, s_case_id is derived from a function that populated that field in this temp table. s_case_id and case_id may be different, however, s_case_id takes precedence.

The custom string part was me trying to do something along the lines of a concat with the additional fields appended on, however, I'm unsure of how to iterate through this list given the conditions.

As you can tell, the preferred output is just the cutomStrings stuck together with the date prefixed.

What is the best and most efficient way of doing this? We have something like 16m records.

Comment: Check out PIVOT

Comment: Isn't this just string aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with your_temporary_table(s_case_id,    case_id,customString,last_updated_date, udef_field_name,value_set) as
(

 select 10 ,    10,     'Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Parking Meter #: xxxxxxx',   '2023-01-04 17:35:08.000',  'Parking Meter #','xxxxxxx' union all
select 10 , 10,     'Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Permit Valid From: 08 Dec 2008',     '2023-01-04 17:35:07.000',  'Permit Valid From','08 Dec 2008'union all
select 10 , 10,     'Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Permit Valid To: 12 Dec 2008',   '2023-01-04 17:35:07.000',  'Permit Valid To' , '12 Dec 2008'union all
select 10 , 10,     'Jan 4 2023 5:35PM Receipt # (if applicable):: xxxxx',  '2023-01-04 17:35:07.000',  'Receipt # (if applicable):', 'xxxxx'
)
select c.s_case_id,c.case_id,
STRING_AGG(c.udef_field_name+c.value_set,',')concatt
from your_temporary_table as c
group by c.s_case_id,c.case_id
```

could you please try something like this